# Suggested edit content change while being reviewed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, suggested-edits

Basically, I rejected the addition of "test12345" to a post as (minor case of) vandalism. Got to the next to-be-reviewed post, everything fine so far. Out of interest (amount of robo-accepts) I switched back in the browser history and actualized the page. There it showed that I've reviewed that post already, and the decisions of other reviewers.

The funny thing is, the text changed in the meantime. Not much better, but nothing vandalism-like anymore, and it got some accepts too.

Maybe I'm too stupid to understand the system, but how is this possible? If it was another edit, shouldn't it get its own review page?

[Here is the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4598930) (All votes together it got rejected, but that's not the problem) If it was another edit, I think it shouldn't overwrite the old one's review.

Comment: (And, why so many people here hate line breaks?)

Comment: Your original revision looked more like a poem...not much todo with hate...this is much better and TheGuyWithThaeHat fixed a couple of typo's when he was at it.

Comment: People don't hate line breaks @deviantfan - they like readable posts as this is a question and answer site and the point of the entire thing is for a post to be easily understandable and consistent with established norms. As this is not a poem the line breaks are inconsistent with those norms. Your question is meant to be prose, make it prose.

Comment: Was there ever an answer to this? I just realised that when I suggested an edit, and then went an added some more to the edit, because I realised I missed something, the suggested edit instance stays the same. So when I suggested the edited edit, it ALREADY had two 'approves' before anyone was able to even see it

Comment: @Illidanek: Glad to see I´m not the only one, so it´s really a bug and not my fault :) Until now, there was no reaction other than the linebreak-comments above. But there are many more open bugs here (older ones than mine too), so it´s not that unusual...

Comment: (and another occurance: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5025459 When I reviewed, it wasn´t improved but worse then before. After I reviewed...)

Comment: I just got this myself. It now looks like I voted to reject a valid and useful edit suggestion, when I only rejected an earlier version of that edit suggestion.

Comment: [Just happened to me and possibly another reviewer here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6110058). The original edit deleted the entire answer and replaced it with "Thanks, worked for me." Now it shows a code fragment which is still grounds for rejection, but for an entirely different reason.

Answer (score 4):

Until a suggested edit has been approved or rejected, the editor can continue editing, potentially resulting in *very* different edits being seen by each reviewer.

Normally, that doesn't happen - folks will re-edit to fix a few typos they missed the first time around, but making dramatic changes (particularly when the first set of changes is poor) isn't a very good strategy as it's very difficult for the editor to know when his edit will be reviewed.

But it is *possible*. And the longer a given edit stays in review, the more possible it is that the editor will submit additional edits.

Consider the alternative you suggest, where subsequent edits resulted in multiple review tasks: fixing a typo on your first edit would then require an additional set of reviewers. And what if the first edit is rejected? At best, this is unnecessary busywork; at worst, it would open the door for malicious people to generate an unlimited number of edit tasks by simply repeatedly editing a single post - each notifying the author, even if rejected.

A better alternative would be to simply block further editing until the first edit is reviewed. But, this ignores the tendency of most folks to not notice minor mistakes until after clicking "submit"...

Comment: An even better alternative would be to reset any "accept" votes.

Comment: Wouldn't have mattered for the example deviantfan gave - the only outstanding review was "reject".

Comment: (How about resetting "all" votes on this review task, accepts and rejects?)