# Edit Review shows only comment and no changes to the post

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just got an [edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5101847) that displayed only a comment (with an email address) - no diff on the rendered output, and it doesn't even have a link to show the markdown diff (maybe because there was no change).

[image: Review of a suggested edit that makes no change]

How did this happen? Does the system allow proposed edits that don't actually change the content? If the review interface can recognize that there was no change to the markdown, couldn't the edit interface notice the same thing and not allow it to be suggested in the first place?

Comment: That is bizarre. I have no idea how that was submitted.

Comment: Wait, nobody rejected it as 'too minor'? Huh, seems like that'd be the obvious choice.

Comment: "Invalid" seemed more appropriate, since the interface was showing no change at all.

Comment: Found another apparently-empty revision (comment only, no content change): http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24003918/4

Comment: Removing changes within grace period would produce that, no?

Comment: That could be it. If that is what happened with the suggested edit, I think the system ought to have automatically dropped it from the queue.

Comment: Changed after reviewed etc.etc. => probably connected with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250131/suggested-edit-content-change-while-being-reviewed (shameless self-advertisment :p)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was no grace period issue here. The person who suggested the edit made no change; the edit form was submitted as presented (whether accidentally or due to misunderstanding, I don't know).

As you can see, the title of the latest revision of that question ends in "....", but the question title does not. Such unnecessary punctuation is automatically removed on submission, but the edit that appended those dots was made in March of 2011, and the auto-removal was only added in July of that year. Apparently we then made that change retroactively to the rendered posts, but not to the revision data. I can see arguments for and against that, but neither way  creates any major problems. And in this case, it actually uncovered a bug, and that's definitely a plus :)

The edit suggestion went through because the "has anything changed?" check is made against the post's current content, but both the editor content and the suggested edit diff are based on the post's current revision. If it weren't for the above-mentioned retroactive title change, the two would have been identical.

The actual bug here was that the punctuation cleanup was not applied to suggested edits. The "dot dot dot dot" should have been removed when that edit submission was made, but this wasn't the case. This is fixed in the next build.

Comment: I tested this when I made my example. Trailing ...'s *were* removed from the (suggested) edits unless I added characters (non-visible) after them.  Also, that post did display the trailing `....` randomly, only to vanish the dots after ??? ... I couldn't figure out a recipe to duplicate it.  The revisions list *always* showed the 4 dots while the [revision link](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5387036/3) truncated it to 3 dots!  Wildly inconsistent behavior all around.

Comment: The single revision view isn't truncating, it's replacing the dots with an ellipsis character, consistent with the way titles are displayed on the question page. Regarding the other things you say, it's hard to respond to that without having a precise step-by-step recount of what you did and saw.

Comment: Fair enough. Does the system track multiple edits within the grace period?

Answer (score 18):

I'll go out on a limb and suggest one way it might possibly have happened:

Someone edited tags, and while the edit was in the queue, a synonym-request got approved which undoes the change:

[image: Synonym added]

[This comment from the OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261042/weird-edit-review?cb=1#comment45292_261042)

> Found another apparently-empty revision (comment only, no content change): https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24003918/4

gave me the idea, after looking at the linked revision (description):
[image: Revision description: Edited tags]

Comment: It looks like a possible synonym was made 2 hours *after* the edit was approved.

Comment: No recent synonyms that look applicable to the OP's first/main suggested edit though. (Last synonym for [android] was created in 2012.)

Comment: 9 upvotes just for wild speculation and making things up? Now you're stealing my game!

Comment: @CodyGray, Sure this doesn't explain the question example, but it probably does explain the second instance that the OP mentioned in the comments. ... Also, you've just described half of Meta!

Answer (score 13):

Here's what happened with [that suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5101847):

1. [The API shows that the user changed only the title](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits#order=asc&sort=creation&ids=5387036&filter=!SWJnaN4q4OU1VTaA8V&site=stackoverflow&run=true).
2. The <kbd>rendered output</kbd> and <kbd>markdown</kbd> buttons do not show for title-only changes. ([Example on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/1357))
3. If a user suggests a title edit and then reedits the question title to remove his changes, then no title diff shows in the review page.  (The second edit must be during the grace period and before the suggestion is rejected or approved.)

   Here's [an example I made on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/1356). (Robo-reviewers make this hard on Stack Overflow.)

   [image: Sample review]

Possible factors:

1. Both [the existing title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5387036/revisions) (revision 3) and the suggested title ended with `....`.  Both being identically:

   > How to get gateway and subnet mask details in Android? programmatically ....

   Not counting any non-visible characters.
2. Currently the system will reject any edits that just change the title by adding periods at the end.  (I'm not sure if this applied back in 2011 when the OP added the periods.)

I didn't fully test to see if trailing periods and non-printing characters are needed to do this.  It seems like they might be, maybe.  I didn't want to create too many suggested edits to test it.

Comment: Good answer for the (main) example, maybe edits in the grace-period which change things to "nothing happened" should silently remove the whole revision / edit suggestion...