# Return old colors for review buttons

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design

Today I noticed the new layout of Stack Overflow. I have (almost) no comments; I love it, but the only thing that makes my eyes bleed are the new buttons:

[image: New style for buttons]

They used to be dark and fit in perfectly. The new ones, however, are too bright and just don't fit in with the rest of the page (in my opinion). They attract too much attention from the content itself, so now I spend more time on each review item by being distracted by those colorish buttons rather than concentrating on the item itself.

Comment: Don't forget on Post Your Answer button...

Comment: Another one of those issues that are far exacerbated when you're a moderator. Basically, imagine seeing *several rows of these buttons on screen at a time*.

Comment: 3d buttons also don't fit with the flat theme.

Comment: These new colors are simply atrocious - I can't even read the text on the buttons because of the bright blue.

Comment: +inf. [Here's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261042/edit-review-shows-only-comment-and-no-changes-to-the-post) an example of the old style.

Comment: @matsjoyce They should remain the same ( old )color, but flat.

Comment: I'm usually the first person to complain when anything changes, [no matter how trivial it is](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheyChangedItNowItSucks), but I have to say that I don't mind the new buttons all that much. I wouldn't object to them being a *touch* darker, though - perhaps more like the [Primary Button Blue](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options) used by Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I personally like them. Maybe they're indeed horrible when there are lots of them as @BoltClock pointed out, but the few most (non-moderator) users see aren't that problematic IMO.

Comment: I'd say return colors, font, etc. on everything. The site is now really hard to read on my high DPI display without fussing with scaling. A massive change like this should introduce user selectable themes or something.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I fully agree. Where's the rollback button on this theme change? Seems like it was done with no useability study whatsoever

Comment: @charlietfl They've been testing it for two months on Meta.

Answer (score 28):

Agreed.

I'm a fan of the new design overall, but the buttons just don't seem to fit with everything else; the bright blue stands out from everything on the page (and not in a good way).

One option is to keep the black buttons the way they were kept with the Meta redesign:

[image: Meta Review Buttons]

Another is to redesign them with a subtler blue:

[image: Darker blue]

Or, you could go with the new theme:

[image: Orange]

[image: Black - I believe this is darker than the old ones]

Finally, there's everyone's favorite option:

[image: Unicorns]

Comment: The favorite option is missing some animation.

Comment: make sure it flickers as well, to attract attention to the most important button on the site

Comment: The color in the last option is too dark, IMO. Perhaps a gradient with some white?

Comment: Could we have it twitch from side to side? It needs to really grab people's attention.

Comment: The last one with some (flickering) animation, jumping on its place would be fine.