# Change [Ask Question] button style

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

I was really searching the other time for the Ask Question button.

This is what the page looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

The Ask Question button looks exactly the same as the question filters, so when I was looking for the button to ask a question, I ignored this part of the page, as I "knew" that it was for filtering.

I think it would improve UX if the button stood out, or was at least visually distinct / separated from the filter buttons.

Comment: IIRC, older designs of SO actually *did* distinguish between the "Ask Question" button and the filtering buttons. I don't actually remember how, though.

Comment: I think it was a different color. [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) has a nice red one.

Comment: [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) is particularly distinctive.

Comment: I wasn't really aware of the different stylings of other stack sites. My problem was with stackoverflow.com. Is this the right place to point out this issue?

Comment: Yes, Meta.SO is the right place to point out issues on SO.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say this is a minor thing to discourage abusers from asking their programming questions here.  Folks who are familiar with SE really should know where to find the Ask Question button; it is, after all, in the same relative location on every Stack Exchange site.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247525/why-do-some-ask-question-buttons-on-some-sites-not-stand-out-and-be-attracting

Comment: @Kevin I didn't find the Arqade "ask" button for a whole minute. It just looks like a design element on the page. It so "symmetrical" with the "Arcade" logo on the left...

Comment: @Compass My first impression of Academia's one was that it was the selected filter.

Answer (score 57):

I agree; [the old design](https://web.archive.org/web/20150103020437/https://stackoverflow.com/) had the button right-aligned to distinguish it from other buttons:

[image: Old SO Ask Question button]

The new design squishes them together, so it might be a good idea to either separate them like the old design (the legacy is preserved in the code: the first five buttons are in their own `div` – `mainnavs` – whereas the "Ask Question" button is in one called `askquestion`) or change its color slightly.

[image: Separated buttons]

[image: Black button]

[image: Orange button]

Comment: I like the 3rd one, nice, bright, and visible.

Comment: The orange button option gets my vote.

Comment: I vote for pink one! Why orange and orange everywhere?...

Comment: I think the _Ask Question_ button design should be in line with that of the _Post Your Question_ button as proposed by you in [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283896/2675154) answer. Of course we would go for the unicorn design!

Comment: I think there should be extra spacing for the button, as well as it being orange.

Comment: I want it *red*!

Answer (score -31):

Those buttons are not "filters"; they take you to different pages. "Ask Question" is one of them.

I think it's just fine the way it is.