# Get notified of edit conflicts while working on an edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, user-experience

You get notifications when a post you are viewing has been updated or received new comments. I was surprised to learn that this functionality is not present where it is needed the most -- when you are in the middle of editing a post.

This is a feature request to improve the handling of editing conflicts.  At a minimum, there should no longer be situations where you unknowingly overwrite somebody's edit.

There are some individual questions about (aspects of) this problem [[1]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275359/suggested-edit-shows-changes-which-are-not-mine-why/275365?noredirect=1#comment110587_275365) [[2]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275359/suggested-edit-shows-changes-which-are-not-mine-why/275365?noredirect=1#comment110587_275365) [[3]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250131/suggested-edit-content-change-while-being-reviewed) [[4]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260969/what-makes-an-edit-more-thorough-than-another-and-how-can-i-save-if-mine-is-m), but -- to my surprise -- I have not been able to find an existing feature request to improve the handling of editing conflicts.

(Tangentially, I also note [a recent change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260341/dont-allow-suggested-edits-to-be-finished-while-someone-has-clicked-improve) which slightly alleviates the situation, but by no means resolves it.)

I don't really care how this is resolved; I can imagine at least

- Notify users who have an edit in progress that another incoming edit will cause a conflict

  - I imagine this should be easy to do on top of existing functionality, but it's also the least appealing solution, because it still leaves the user with the burden of handing the merge manually.  It's still way better than accidentally overwriting somebody's edit, and allows you to back out and start over if you are planning a substantial edit, but have not yet made significant changes.
- Offer a colored diff for merging when you are about to save

  - No idea how much harder this would be to do, and whether users are prepared to actually use this (StackOverflow users are probably generally familiar with such tools, but other sites in the SE network might have users who have never seen anything like it).
- Offer to merge automatically, and simply mark the sections where there is a conflict.

  - This is actually probably both easier to implement and easier to use than the previous item.

Comment: This question was triggered by the [recent question about a conflict during the 5-minute grace period](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275359/suggested-edit-shows-changes-which-are-not-mine-why/275365?noredirect=1#comment110648_275365) (link `[1]` above) which might perhaps require some special handling; though I hope that is not the case.

Comment: You should already be getting this -- if I have a question I'm editing, and someone else edits, it shows the "new edit made" banner or whatever. What browser are you using? I know it must support websockets to have this feature.

Comment: Related feature request from MSE: [Preventing conflicting simultaneous edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/preventing-conflicting-simultaneous-edits).  This is marked as [meta-tag:status-completed] as you are supposed to be prompted before submitting the edit.  I think this has been improved since to use the websockets as @hichris123 indiciates.  IIRC the only time when you may silently overwrite an edit is when you are dealing with the grace period.

Comment: When I edit, I simply have a small window open of the original post. That is, I have two windows open. Not only does this help editing, this also notifies the user is another edit has taken place.

Comment: Something like a `git merge` between edits, and alert the user when there is a conflict or too small a difference, would be nice, as then the changes by both the user and the other editing user would be kept.

Comment: Related to this I had two other people editing my first post here at the same time as me and one rolled it back. The author of the post should be encouraged to do the editing themselves so they learn. Some indication that a post is actively being edited might discourage others from jumping in too early.

Answer (score 26):

Eh?

I wish I could accidentally or intentionally overwrite someone else's edit!

I *do* get a notification saying that someone else has edited whatever I am editing.  It also (sometimes?) says that my edit "must be more substantive than the other edit to override" or something to that effect.

My edits in such situations usually are pretty extensive, and usually my edit should win.  But I never have.

My feature request would be to see the other person's changes.  If they are effectively the same as what I have done, then I am happy to abandon my edits.  But the situation always seems to be that I am blind to what has happened and am forced to either "copy", abandon, and then reedit to see what else needs fixing, or just giving up.

Comment: Sometimes opening a second tab is best. Anyway, how would you want to see the other persons changes? Many choices, none really good, and the better ones seem to be quite difficult.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  The standard diff display (when reviewing edits or looking at editing history) would be fine.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  I just ran into this situation and opened another tab into the same question.  My edits were more extensive, but I could find no way to save them.  Grrrrr!

Comment: How and where shall they be displayed? (And I'm feeling with you... far too literally even.)

Comment: @Deduplicator:  Above or below the editing box.  Or a pop up.  I don't care.  Just so I know what I am seeing, can figure out how to (or if I need to) dismiss it, and continue editing.

Comment: Ah, how about this: Add a revision selector, and chooser between diff/markdown-diff/markdown/render to the preview. Cause if the other one did something more than substitute two words, you might have to look a bit more careful.

Comment: I tried to get the "more substantive" message explained some time ago, but didn't really get an answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260969/what-makes-an-edit-more-thorough-than-another-and-how-can-i-save-if-mine-is-m. It never made sense to me. It's somewhat better now since you get exclusive access for a few minutes when you start editing posts in the edit review queue.

Comment: I swear I've managed to get my edit through by folding their edits into mine...