# Pending edits should be advertised

Tags: feature-request, edits

People editing question should know that an edit is pending.
Once again, I was correcting a question on SO. It was edited, so I reloaded the page, to notice that the edit made was not good enough. So I edited again, had to start over my edit, and in the end, someone was quicker than me.

It's frustrating and encourages people to edit a question very quickly rather than in depth. Shouldn't there be a lock or some notification that the question is being edited by someone else?

This is my first request here, so I hope I respect the format and that the question was not asked before.

Comment: Why don't you just wait 6 to 8 hours?  Nobody is going to get in your way after that.  Just click the "star" to keep track of it.  With non-zero odds that you don't have to make the effort.

Comment: What happens if it's locked and then the person doesn't complete the edit? The question remains unedited, and no one else can do so. Learn to live with it, or wait a while before doing your edit. You share this site with several million others; you have to learn to deal with issues that arise as a result.

Comment: I do not have any solution but maybe a great idea can arise :)

Comment: @HansPassant We want content to be edited quickly so that it becomes more readable sooner--the majority of views on most posts happen in the first hours, and if the edit comes through before then then we save time for that many people.

Comment: Do you mean *in progress* edits or edits that are awaiting approval/rejection? There *is* a notification of when an edit is awaiting approval/rejection. (Also, "under edition" is an incorrect phrase in English, I believe. Maybe "being edited"?)

Comment: somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275398/get-notified-of-edit-conflicts-while-working-on-an-edit

Comment: There should *really* be a lock mechanism. I've spent like 5 full minutes formatting an awful question, and without notice, the new edit was loaded. Except the new one is bad as well; and now I don't want to start over.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831664/access-mode-in-mkdir-sys-call-linux-c