# Please add a temporary freeze on editing posts when someone starts editing

Tags: feature-request, edits

(I couldn't find this request on Meta after looking. Related question [Unknowingly Editing an Edited Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266295/unknowingly-editing-an-edited-post) and a very similar but *different* request: [Pending edits should be advertised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288577/pending-edits-should-be-advertised))

I saw [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679838/how-can-i-display-an-element-on-hover-of-another) by a new user that had a poorly-worded title, so I opened the question to improve the title. In the course of doing so, I saw much of the post needed improvements as well, so I started making changes. Halfway through my initial revision, I saw a grey line pop-up that said "this question has been edited", so I finished the bit I was editing, and then hit "Save Edits", not wanting to lose my progress, and saw the post had been edited by meagar, whose edit was much smaller than mine and also an edit that was achieved by my more-comprehensive edit already.

What I *didn't* see, that I expected to, was a big red warning message that said "Warning, another user has edited this post. Yours will be rejected unless it is more substantial". Now, sometimes I *do* see that warning. Why didn't I see it this time? And can we fix that?

Now, as it turns out, my edit was *combined* with meagar's (no notification of this, however. I had to find out for myself while checking the revisions ex post facto). I saw meagar make another edit with a bit more substance, but still less than my original one, so I rolled back to mine, thinking it was still the only revision to accept based on total substance.

This led to a messy couple of minutes and an unintentional edit duel (I wouldn't quite call it a *war*) that even roped in a passing moderator (I had hoped to link to the comments, but BoltClock has already cleaned them up. I had commented to let meagar know I was making substantial edits, and BoltClock said "No, let the budding moderator do it.").

Now I don't have a problem with the comments clean up (though it's a minor annoyance that I can't link to them), or that someone else also wanted to make edits in good faith. The problem I have here is that the scenario **shouldn't have happened at all**; meagar should not have been *able* to start editing the post to begin with, since I was already in the process of editing it.

So my request is similar to the (somewhat new) Review Queue freeze:

Please freeze a post's edit feature (let's say for two minutes) while an edit is already underway. The OP (and possibly moderators) should be able to override this, due to his or her unique qualifications of adding new information to the question.

Comment: That comment was meant in good humor btw, though I can see why it might not have been taken as such in this situation.

Comment: The problem there is that people can either maliciously or unintentionally hold a lock without actually spending time improving a post, preventing anyone else from doing anything.

Comment: Rather than temporarily freezing editing, what about simply notifying the user that someone else is actively editing the post at the same time?

Comment: As it is non-trivial to grab the source of a post some times, I will find myself clicking 'edit' to get at the raw markdown.  (the non-trivial way: grab the url, tweak 'questions' to 'posts' and title slug to 'revisions', http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/290465/revisions then click on 'source' which gives you the [raw source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/24c758fd-99fc-46df-a5dd-8fb1088a2a9f/view-source) ... but that's a multi step process compared to 'edit' and 'copy' and a pain if there are no other revisions - and answers are even more complicated in that initial step)

Comment: @BoltClock I did take it as humor. I was just going to use it to reference your passing by.

Comment: @Servy I don't think this behavior exists. Maliciously preventing someone from improving a post? You wouldn't know someone else wanted to improve it beforehand. Do you have any example of it? Anyway, two minutes is really not that long, and once it's up, others can start editing again like they can now. If people are really hampered by this, then it just means they get to move on to new questions to edit that much quicker.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Because that's an additional, unnecessary step that invites stress, confusion, concern, etc. "Oh, someone else is editing? Is my edit better? Is theirs? What parts are they editing? I've wasted a click and sometime by starting an edit that might be superseded" etc. This feature would simply prevent that step from happening.

Comment: @TylerH Why do people do anything malicious?  It's one way to troll people, just keep opening up posts for editing to stop people from fixing problems.  As for unintentional cases, it's easy enough to open for editing and then navigate away, open up the window and then get pulled way from the compute, lose your connection, etc.  Tons of ways to start editing and not finish.  If the lock time is short enough to not be a bother, then it's not long enough to make a comprehensive edit.  If it's long enough to allow for comprehensive edits, they'll frequently inhibit quality edits.

Comment: Your proposed feature would add *more* stress, confusion, concern, etc.  Currently editing conflicts happen, but they're largely quite rare, and are not hard at all to manage.

Comment: @Servy If there is really abuse in this form (I doubt it. Maybe we can assuage your fears by making it a privilege? "Editing a post locks other users out for a very short time" at 2k/5k/10k or something) then it should and will be flagged for moderators, assuming they don't also write some code to detect when people click "edit" and don't make any changes.

Comment: @Servy Obviously I disagree; I think you're missing the point. It's to serve as an *impassable* notification that someone else has already started editing the post. I *do* think there needs to be better management of the red "your post needs to be more substantial than the one that was just made" warning, but that's *not enough*. Preventing conflicting edits *only* reduces confusion/stress/concern. It moves the onus of responsibility for editing something off of you, the concerned passerby.

Comment: @Servy Also re: concern about 2 mins not being enough to make a comprehensive edit... sure, you can't re-write a 10-paragraph question in that time, but most questions are not hugely involved, and a substantial edit (relative to the amount of text) only takes a minute or two. Further, as the timer draws closer to 0, a simple notice can appear "your edit lock is about to expire. It's recommended that you save your edit now and continue again if you're still making changes." for questions that are 1> day old. But yes, after the lock expires, other users should **always** get that  red warning.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not missing you're point, I simply disagree with it.  You seem to be radically overestimating how often edit conflicts happen, how hard they are to resolve, and underestimating the problems that would arise by locking posts for editing every time someone starts editing.  I've spent a lot of time editing a lot of posts; I've found editing conflicts to happen extremely rarely, and fixing up after them is not hard at all.  You're trying to solve a problem that just *isn't a problem that needs solving*.

Comment: People making very short edits are people who *aren't going to have many conflicting edits* because they're, by definition, short.  And when they do happen, since they're small edited, they're easy to resolve after the fact.  It's only larger edits that are both more likely to result in conflicts, and take more time to resolve when there is a conflict, that really need to be considered here.  If you don't address that case, then your solution isn't even solving the minuscule problem that exists.

Comment: @Servy *How* hard they are to solve or *how* often they happen isn't the primary concern. It happened, so it's a concern. Time is our most precious commodity. It took *time* for me to make that edit and *time* for meagar to make his, and it took (read: wasted) additional time for us both because of the conflicts/lack of clarity surrounding the edit system. Preventing those conflicts from happening only *saves* time. I have edited a lot of posts, too, and this doesn't happen very often. But when it does, it's a *big* annoyance. This solution solves it for all problems, miniscule or otherwise.

Comment: How often something happens and the magnitude of the problems it causes are of *enormous* concern when determining whether or not to develop a feature to address the problem.  Adding a feature like this takes quite a lot of effort to develop; creating solutions for problems that aren't actually problems means not solving a problem that is *actually a problem*.  You talk about wasted time, and yet aren't considering all of the time that would be wasted by people not able to make edits because of your proposal, or quality edits that wouldn't be made at all.

Comment: No, the solution doesn't solve all of the problems.  If you want the lock time to be very small, then the large, time consuming edits that are the most likely to actually result in conflicts are exactly the edits that this wouldn't help.  You're not even solving the problem that you're setting out to solve in the cases where it's most likely to happen, and that takes the most work to resolve when it happens.  And that's not even getting into all of the many new problems it causes.

Comment: @Servy The first step, however, is acknowledging the problem. Just because you don't seem bothered by this problem, **doesn't mean it's not a problem**, so please kindly stop repeating that falsehood. Regarding the meat of your comment: I *am* considering all the time that would be saved* (not wasted) by peoples' edits no longer being overwritten. Those people would then go back to the main line of productivity. 1/2

Comment: @Servy 2/2 Moderation is a *diversionary behavior* from productivity. We take time away from asking/answering to fix problems with the platform. It is simple logic that we try to make that diversionary behavior last as short a time as possible. This lock wouldn't cause any problems, from what I can see. If you read the post, you'll see it *solves* them by preventing them from happening. Feel free to enumerate on these new problems instead of just saying it will "cause some".

Comment: The first step is *determining if there is a problem*.  The fact that you think it is a problem **doesn't mean it's actually a problem**, so please kindly stop repeating that falsehood.  You need to actually demonstrate the there is a significant problem, and that it merits such a solution, which is something you haven't done.

Comment: @Servy I determined there was a problem when my contribution ran into a conflict with another member's contribution and there was no clear system or guideline in place to handle it/prevent it. That's the point of the big feature-request I made at the top. If you don't think it's a problem, that's fine, you can downvote as you've done and move on. But it is most definitely a problem for me, and since Meta represents only a small fraction of the actions/behavior/people of the site, it's sound to assume that means it's a problem for dozens, if not scores and scores, of people.

Comment: @TylerH But it *doesn't* always solve the problems, it only *sometimes* solves the problems, and I've already listed several problems with this feature; I didn't feel the need to repeat them.  If you want me to I can.  There is the potential for abusive or unintentional locks to be held when they shouldn't have been, there will be people prevented from making quality edits that they could otherwise have made, and of course as with any feature ever, there are the large costs that go into implementing the feature, and the opportunity costs of not fixing a more important problem.

Comment: So because you had one edit conflict ones proves that this is a significant, regular, frequently occurring problem with large scale negative consequences for a large number of users?  Sorry, but no; the fact that you had one edit conflict doesn't demonstrate that this is a significant problem.  Saying that this is a problem for a few dozen people, out of a site of hundreds of thousands of users, is to say it's a minuscule problem.  In fact, as you've only had it happen to you once doesn't even mean it's a significant problem for you, let alone the other 99.999% of the site's users.

Comment: @Servy I've had these conflicts before; I never said this was the first time. This one prompted me to make a post on Meta about it. It is not a common occurrence, but it is a time-consuming and frustrating one. I don't want it to *ever* happen again to anyone. Hence the feature request of a short, two minute lock for questions 24h or younger. This is the same behavior we have for posts in the review queues. I don't see why it's vehemently opposed by you here where it would have a *greater* positive impact on moderation time reduction than where it was introduced for that in the first place.

Comment: Your justification for why this is a significant problem that merits a significant investment to solve was that it happened to you once.  Even it happening to you a few times doesn't come anywhere close to demonstrating that it's a significant problem.  Again, a short lock *doesn't* prevent this problem from happening "ever again" as you're claiming.  It would only prevent it from happening *for very quick edits*.  The queue doesn't prevent the post from being edited, it *prevents other reviewers from being asked to review that item.  That's a *radically* different situation.

Comment: @Servy I just re-read my post and all of my comments; nowhere did I claim this is the first time it's happened to me.

Comment: That's correct, but you did claim that this is a problem that needs solving simply because you had an edit conflict once: `I determined there was a problem when my contribution ran into a conflict with another member's contribution and there was no clear system or guideline in place to handle it/prevent it.`.  You said that because it happened to you that one time, this is a significant problem that now needs to be solved.  You have come nowhere close to demonstrating that this is actually a significant problem.

Comment: @Servy That's a difficult task, since "significant" is subjective. From my point of view, one instance is significant, even if it's the first time I've encountered the problem over hundreds of actions.

Comment: SE doesn't spend enormous resources building complex features spending many person-weeks of work (at a minimum) because one person had one problem once that took them a few minutes of their time to completely fix.

Comment: @Servy Aside from the fact that my problem was never resolved (I had to abandon my efforts), they should. It's sort of their job. I'm not demanding this be put on the top of the list or implemented right away on the whim of one user, but it *is* a problem that I think needs addressing, or at the very least some discussion with the community as a whole/the developers behind the system, rather than a two-hour tête-à-tête with another regular user w/ no stake who's on the other side of the aisle.

Comment: It's their job to spend the limited resources that they have as wisely as they can to best improve the quality of the site for everyone.  If they had unlimited resources then yes, saying, "this was some minor inconvenience to me this once" is something that could be looked at.  In the real world, with a limited number of things that can be worked on, something needs to be a significant problem, with a very large benefit to merit adding involved new features.

Comment: Still coming across this twice today; tried to edit two questions where each one had 2+ revisions by separate individuals that were slightly less comprehensive than mine each time. A notice that someone else recently opened the post for editing is direly needed.