# Is there a way to see if someone else is editing a question?

Tags: support, edits

Many times I find new questions on Stack Overflow that need some editing, either because the user needs some help with code formatting or because English may not be their first language.

Sometimes, understanding and changing the phrasing of the question is an involved process which might even take several minutes.

However, often times when I am nearing completion of my edits, a helpful yet aggravating orange bar pops up at the top of my screen, informing me that I was too slow: someone else has already made edits to the question.

Usually, they have changed the majority of what I have changed, making it not worth it to submit my changes as well.

This is somewhat annoying, as my time editing that question was wasted. If I had known someone else was working on it, I wouldn't have bothered.

I don't care about adding a lock, like [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/please-add-a-temporary-freeze-on-editing-posts-when-someone-starts-editing) suggests. I just want to know if there is a way to tell if someone is editing a question.

Comment: This [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280892/this-answer-is-now-being-edited-by-user-label-when-a-post-is-being-edited) could be related.

Comment: No, there is no way to do so. The [feature-request] mentioned by @MarounMaroun is still waiting for a reaction by Stack Exchange employees, so I doubt it will be implemented soon / at all.

Comment: Indeed, this is a duplicate. I wonder why it didn't show up originally when I searched... Seeing that the related post is two year old doesn't give me hope.