# Is there anything you can do to not seem like an idiot when edits collide?

Tags: discussion, edits

I made an edit to a question. At the same time somebody else did also. Just before I committed mine that edit was committed. The result was that it seemed that like I edited one space char and so on. You can imagine how glad the reviewers were. If not then take a look:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18163614

Is there anything that can be done to avoid situations like this?

So - although the comment was good - I am not asking things like

> How does the review queue handle the order of suggested reviews?

My question stands still. It is not a question how the system works or how the queues are handled but about if there is something that can be done by

- Me
- Not me

to avoid situations like this?

And yet a from the duplos answer

> We should ideally find a way to fix the system so this doesn't happen
>   in the future.

About comments suggesting this as a duplo of

> Get notified of edit conflicts while working on an edit

not totally wrong. But it seems not to work now and might never.

Maybe more something that allows reviewers see the situation and to put the edit like 'disputed flag' or so. Or some 'grace period' during which there will not be need for a decisions like this.

Comment: Related feature-request [Get notified of edit conflicts while working on an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275398/get-notified-of-edit-conflicts-while-working-on-an-edit) which deals with a similar situation (conflicts instead of weird auto-merged suggestions).

Comment: As of right now there's nothing you can do, except making it to 3k rep so you don't have to go through a review queue, this dramatically reduces the audience who'll ever see what you just did, but doesn't really remove the problem. I've had edit-collisions with post owners where I've effectively reversed a large edit to fix some other problems and at 3k+ there is no reveiw to save you when that happens and you'll have to fix the mess yourself. Good news is you can do it instantly. I would say the "getting notified" one isn't a duplicate but it would be needed in order to say "yes" on this one.

Comment: @ivarni the magic happens at 2k rep ;)

Comment: I stand corrected then, it's been a while. Well then OP is even closer to this not being such a big issue :)

Comment: @Sinatr No, the edit was rejected. The link is in the question https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18163614 Too many and one may get banned for editing.