# Edit reviewers are given misleading information

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I was going to edit somebody's question but I promptly got warned that my last edit was rejected, that's odd I thought. Looking into it I noticed that somebody else had gotten their edit approved right before mine. Because of that the point of view from the edit reviewers makes it look like my edit was totally meaningless and thus, of course, rejecting it.

- [Here is my edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27571776)
- [Here are the applied edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64736662/revisions)

It seems unfair that I get a bad 'edit score' because somebody else posted an edit a few seconds before me. This could surely be improved somehow.

Comment: [Unfortunately, in the past 3 years, no one has yet come up with a way to avoid looking like an idiot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360272/is-there-anything-you-can-do-to-not-seem-like-an-idiot-when-edits-collide?noredirect=1). I'll check with the R&D department on the status of that time machine.