# Wrongly banned from editing

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, edit-ban

I recently [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30995843), correcting grammar and converting image links to images.

My edit was accepted once by a reviewer, but shortly after, the question author edited his question to include his code (instead of images), and in the edit review queue **it showed up as if I removed his code and used images instead.**

A few days later, I am now **banned from editing until April 6th 2022** due to two edit queue reviewers *(being helpful and seeing this very destructive looking edit)* rejecting the edit and marking it as:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
> or is deliberately destructive.

I'd like to know if Stack Overflow is planning to fix this in future, how they plan to prevent this from happening to other users, and if this ban will be revoked.

**NB: No offence to the two reviewers; they were just doing their best to help the site.**

Comment: @yivi More likely the edits conflicted with each other. Not the fault of the editor

Comment: *"it showed up as if I removed his code and used images instead."* - I thought that _might_ be the case. But I have to review based on what I see.

Comment: The suggested edit was posted 3 minutes after the asker's edit, so it's possible the edit process for the rejected edit was started before the asker's edit was posted.

Comment: @yivi I have seen it a few times. It's basically timing. The editor starts editing, in the meantime the author edits, but the version that the editor is editing remains old. When submitted it looks like they are removing the revision from the author

Comment: @Dharman Yeah, it's _supposed_ to only let in progress edits continue _if_ they are more substantial than the conflicting edit, but I fail to see how that's the case here. But then SO has plenty jank in its systems.

Comment: FWIW, that edit was worth rejecting even without the conflict. It wasn't improving a lot and it unnecessarily made the text bold.

Comment: **Your edit was indeed destructive.**  You removed the only code in the question.  The only text that remained was bolded for some strange reason.  The review indicates the first approve vote was at 12:44 which is 13 minutes after the first edit that ADDED the code.  Even if we ignore that point, bolding text for no reason, is NOT helpful.

Comment: @yivi Based on the testimony of the person who wrote this Meta post and the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70997945/timeline) The suggested edit was submitted < 3 minutes after OP edited it.

Comment: Also FWIW, I was more interested in the approving reviewer being review banned than you being edit banned (although given your plagiarism one in Robert's answer which I also rejected, I think potentially you still should be).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anything you can do to not seem like an idiot when edits collide?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360272/is-there-anything-you-can-do-to-not-seem-like-an-idiot-when-edits-collide) - Also see that posts "Linked" posts.

Comment: I personally have zero patience for plagiarism.  It's to my knowledge universally accepted in nearly all developed countries that, plagiarism is something, you should avoid.  It's primary an academic concern, but even in the professional world, it's unacceptable.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no automatic ban for edit suggestion except for anonymous editors, and one edit conflict (however bad it is) is unlikely to make a mod ban you. So, a higher chance is that a mod decided to manually review your *past suggested edits* and took an action based on it.

Answer (score 28):

- Converting image links of code to images of code is not useful, nor is making sentences all bold
- [Plagiarism isn't useful either](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30930677)
- And nor is using [code fencing to mark things as code if they aren't actually code](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30837681)

So overall, it's probably best to use this time out to review what makes a good edit.