# A diamond moderator deleted my answer. Why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, grace-period

[This mod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658090/copy-html-code-to-clipboard/26658137#26658137).

1. Was this warranted? The only reason I can see is that the post was closed as a duplicate, but I've never seen (good) answers deleted just because the question was closed.
2. Does this carry a penalty of some sort?

---

[image: screenshot]

The [help center link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) is generic.

Comment: have you been posting the same answer to a whole bunch of different questions?

Comment: @Servy Nope. This was a 100% original answer. I had made an edit, but it appears to have been within the grace period.

Comment: It should not have been deleted, it seems George has not been paying much attention today while working the flag queue.  That happens.

Comment: It probably was flagged as NAA by a user, and George may well have thought it wasn't a sufficient answer by itself.  I wouldn't have deleted it.  Note, I wish they listed flag-reasons that applied to an answer that is deleted, when it's deleted with flags on it - just like closed Qs find out what close reason was used.

Comment: @HansPassant The version that was deleted looked nothing like the version the user is showing here. That's important.

Comment: Well, the 5 minute edit window has been around a long time.

Comment: The key fact here is that the edit was made well after George had already moved on to the next flag, @Hans - with or without the grace period, that'd still have been too late to avoid the deletion. There are a couple of ways we could improve this: canned deletion comments for mods (as we have in review) would've given Mooseman a better idea of what was going on, while resetting the grace period upon deletion would've given *everyone else* a better view of what happened.

Comment: It might be a good idea for non-OP actions (i.e. deletion by a diamond mod or the community) during the grace period to force a revision checkpoint so that edits before and after the deletion can be distinguished.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I just posted a feature request to that effect: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275705/final-binding-votes-to-close-and-delete-should-trigger-a-revision-to-be-saved

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773) would work about as good as your feature request

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your original answer was much different than the one you've screenshotted. [You even commented such](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275701/a-diamond-moderator-deleted-my-answer-why#comment112086_275701):

> @Servy Nope. This was a 100% original answer. I had made an edit, but it appears to have been within the grace period. –  Mooseman 18 mins ago

Your *original* answer was deleted, and it looked *nothing like the version* you edited it into.

I don't remember the exact text of the answer; but it was something to the effect of:

> "Use Flash."

I asked @Shog9 to try to pull up the original text; but he was unable to.

It was deleted for a few reasons:

1. It added no useful knowledge to the question
2. Any information was already contained in the duplicated question.

I understand you're frustrated; but it'd be more helpful to show the community your original answer and have them judge the deletion on the merits of what it was originally (and what I deleted), and not what it was edited into.

It's also important to note that you edited your answer four minutes after I deleted it; just shy of the five minute tracking window.

As a show of good faith, I've undeleted the answer you edited it into.

Comment: weird. I didn't realize that edits made during the grace period were tracked at all. I don't see any edits on the answer

Comment: @KevinB Edits made within the five minute initial window aren't shown and unfortunately aren't trackable internally either. It's an edge case; but as this has proven, it doesn't help when it happens.

Comment: Is this the same thing that causes [an issue with suggested edit review queues being out of sync with actual edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250131/suggested-edit-content-change-while-being-reviewed)

Comment: @Compass I don't have the answer, but @@Shog9 might.

Comment: You can continue modifying a suggested edit up until it is approved or rejected, @Compass. I don't believe there's even a grace period there - as long as the edit is still pending, you can keep working on it. Normally it's pretty dumb to submit a woefully incomplete edit and then try to patch it up before it is reviewed, but it's pretty common for folks to forget a comma or miss a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Was it warranted? It's not the greatest answer of all time (of course, that's largely due to the poor question). It wasn't a link-only answer though.

One reason to delete it would be that if you got an upvote, the Roomba couldn't clean the question up; though if he was that concerned about it, I would expect him to just delete the whole question.

As to a penalty, it won't hurt you at all. Negatively voted answers that are deleted would contribute to an answer-ban, but you had 0 score. With your reputation; even if it *was* negatively voted, you likely have more than enough good answers to make such a ban nigh-on impossible, so it wouldn't affect you anyways.

Hopefully he'll see this thread and answer, but as it stands, don't worry about it.

Comment: It's approximately impossible for a 10k user to end up answer banned.  You'd hit a manual ban long before making it to the many hundreds if not thousands of heavily downvoted an deleted answers it would take to balance out the existing contributions.

Comment: @Servy I realize that (and thought about including it in my post) but for the benefit of other, lower rep users, I included it. I'll edit to mention it though.

Comment: This should carry a penalty for the moderator.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I might agree with you... except the OP wasn't telling the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do when you edit an answer that was deleted - or you edit your answer and *then* find it deleted, as may well have happened here - is to flag the answer for un-deleting.  You don't need to come to meta for this, and shouldn't.  Think of it as a re-open vote for an answer.

You can also simply make a new answer, but I wouldn't do that unless your new answer is so different from the old one that there's no real relationship - ie, it won't look like you're just reposting the deleted answer.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP did not just want the post undeleted but wanted to learn what the rationale was, in the event that the post should remain deleted.