# Voting the question vs. Voting the answer

Tags: discussion, voting

In another question I asked about [Are the hurried downvoters improving this community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275709)
I received many comments, one of them was

> You are seriously suggesting that we cast votes less often? This might
>   not be the right place for you. The voting system is integral to
>   making this site work. Good rises to the top; bad is forced to the
>   bottom and dealt with. BTW, totally agree that a "trend" of voting
>   based on our opinions of posts is something to be desired. I would
>   upvote Andrew Barbers comment, but I'm out of votes

Excuse me if I am not familiar with the system of SE, I can understand voting the answers makes good ones rise to the top and bad ones forced to the bottom, but I can't understand this mechanism on questions?!

My point in the other question was about hurried votes on the questions and not on the answers and suggested its better to find a more balanced way for it and counted the harms of that trend to the community .... (I can't explain it here but you can find it there)

I usually don't pay much attention to the votes of a question but the answer. I never sorted them on their votes, I usually have a problem, google it and if I find it in this site regardless of the number of up-votes of the question if it meets my problem, I click it.then it decrease the importance of votes for the questions as the above comment suggests. Moreover duplicated questions are closed and there is not a race for similar questions.

Most people are redirected from search engines to the site to find an answer for their questions, then their questions for them is important than any other question. few people check other questions and use this site for study or learning purpose.

Really what is the aim of that mechanism for the questions and its importance?

Comment: To give a quick and not complete overview: Voting helps promote good content, and point out content that isn't so good, needs improvement, or flat out does not belong on SO.

Comment: And to follow @Kendra, it does not matter if that content is a question or an answer. It should be treated equally.

Comment: But for the questions it is not that serious and indicator as it is for answers

Comment: The help center contains an article that explains the voting system, and why it's important for the site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: To add a little bit more, I don't know if you've seen it or not but [this help center page does explain why voting is important.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) Of course, if you don't understand something in the page, feel free to cite it here and explain what about it you don't understand. :)

Comment: @Kendra I will read it, but I don't ask about voting system, I ask about voting for questions (not answers) and the difference

Comment: @Ahmad I know, and that page does address both questions and answers together, but it might still help you see why it helps with questions. On top of that, Bradley's answer sums it up pretty well.

Comment: Here's the excerpt that will probably help most: _"Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information."_

Comment: The [tour] on every single [se] site explains how voting works and the purpose for voting. The hint that appears when you hover over the up or down arrows for voting on a question tells you what each vote indicates. Poor quality questions should be downvoted to indicate that they are poor questions. This is not a garbage collection site, where any old noise passes for a useful question. We have quality standards to keep the value of the site up, and voting is one of the ways to indicate (and enforce) those quality standards. Downvotes also help the automated processes delete bad questions.

Comment: *few people check other questions and use this site for study or learning purpose.*  quite untrue; on 'tough' issues, I find that even UNANSWERED questions can be helpful - perhaps the OP used an approach different from mind which avoided my problem to begin with.  Look at Mr White's scorecard - 6 questions in 5 yrs.  *Maybe* he knows all the answers and never has questions, or maybe he knows how to find the answer for himself

Comment: To add to @Plutonix's point, *answerers* (or "internal users") certainly use the site for much more than answering their own questions. Sometimes to learn or study, but much more often to just find a question they want to answer.

Comment: based on this question I drew a proposal for voting mechanism http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242852

Answer (score 15):

For the record; that was my comment.

Voting on questions does several important things:

- It serves as a memo to other users; saying "look/don't look at this".
- It improves the signal-to-noise ratio of the site. Downvoted questions are taken off the front page and "Recommended" tab. Upvoted questions appear more often.
- It causes posters of repeatedly poor questions to run into rate-limits, which helps keep the site clean. At the extreme level, this leads to a post-ban.
- It gives good askers reputation; and (sometimes) removes it from poor askers.
- It lets the OP know that the community believes the question needs improvement.

These votes are "targeted" towards the OP and answerers. The OP needs to know if his question is of good or bad quality; and the answerers want to know if the question is worth their time. Users coming in from Google won't necessarily see these benefits, but they are vital for the community.

Votes on answers are "targeted" towards the OP and askers (which would include people asking the same question on Google). Again, it indicates quality/acceptance to the OP. For askers, it indicates what answer the community thinks they should use.

In short, voting on questions is just as important as voting on answers. Votes on any post indicate the same thing (on the main site anyways), that the post is (or isn't) useful and of high quality.

[This help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) provides more excellent information on this.

Comment: Worth noting that a series of downvotes on a question can also warn the asker that there is something wrong with their question. If the asker is willing to learn from that, it can lead to said asker posting much better questions in the future.

Comment: @Kendra Excellent point! added.

Comment: But all above are not satisfying important and an answer to the question (I modified it now), who checks the recommended section? Recommended for what? I just look for the answer of my own question., look at this? for what? again I look for the answer to my own questions.

Comment: @Ahmad In response to that: If they don't find their answer on a downvoted question, the downvotes still serve as a signal that the question was not appreciated. If they care to get their answer, they better be sure not to make their question look like the downvoted one. (Not saying people actually pay attention to it, but that's the point.) Otherwise, voting isn't really for external users when it comes to questions. It's for internal moderation.

Comment: @Ahmad (cont.) Since the site is user-moderated (in other words, the moderation is not just in the hands of the moderators, but also in the hands of the active users such as myself (for low rep example) and BradleyDotNET (for high rep example)) and users can downvote questions, users can signal to other users that something isn't right and the post might need help. For example, I don't have full editing privilege. If I felt a post was bad and needed editing, but I didn't feel I could get it through review, I could downvote and maybe even leave a comment.

Comment: @Ahmad The "Recommended" tab is a tab on the home page. Its *supposed* to show you questions an algorithm thinks you would be interested in (work-in-progress). *Answerers* would use it to find questions to answer.

Comment: @Kendra Thank you, it seems its more important for the moderators and internal users who like to answer questions and not for the external uses who are directed to a question.

Comment: @Ahmad Unquestionably, question votes are more for the OP and answerers, as opposed to googlers.

Comment: @Ahmad Pretty much, yes. The only way it really concerns external users is if their question is not answered and they want to become an internal user to re-ask it. Of course, in that case, they're still likely to ignore it but they realize fast what that negative number was for.

Comment: Yeah I got its importance for the answerers, then votes for the questions are more important for the internal users and votes for the answers more important to the external users, but there is not really a race for the questions as it is for the answers, and I expect different approaches toward them, all in all, Thank you

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I suggest you mention the different category of users of the site in your answer and mention their difference, the internal and external users and the intentions and aim of each group.

Comment: @Ahmad I tried to explain that in my recent edit. Let me know what you think! If you want to take a stab add it, suggest an edit and I'll look at it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thank you to let me add any suggestion, It was good, but I couldn't edit it so I added another answer which is actually my suggestions for edit, sorry for that. you can delete it after getting the suggestions.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thank you, the reason that I started by introducing the groups of users and not listing the benefits of votes to the question is that without that introduction the reader may doesn't get the importance of them for an external user or a user in general, and for the same reason also I emphased active community members instead of the users in the first item of the list, but thank you for consideration :)

Comment: @Ahmad I did that because the thrust of your question was "Why are question votes valuable?"; not "Who cares about question votes?" I don't mind including an additional explanation; but I always try to *directly* answer the question in the first part of any answer I write.

Answer (score 3):

> I usually have a problem, google it and if I find it in this site regardless of the number of up-votes of the question if it meets my problem, I click it.

You don't have to waste time checking the number of votes because [Google already did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233858/135695)

Answer (score 1):

++ for [BradleyDotNET's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275735/2140173), he's got very valid points but also I'd like to add one more reason votes on questions help me:

I am quite active in Excel/VBA tags and believe me 95% of the questions posted are crap... Sometimes it takes a true while to find a good/interesting (*answerable*) and non duplicate question...

When I come back after a few days of not being active I [put a quick query together](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), something like:

> [vba] score:5 is:question created:[date]..... etc

to see all questions that were scored 5 or higher in the between [date].

So generally, I would say it increases the chances to find *interesting* questions in specific tags.