# Purpose of down-voting

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have trouble understanding the 'down-vote' feature. New users cannot down-vote, it is a privilege. When one receives it, he/she is shown a 'help' page to be taught when to down-vote and when not to do it.

It seems to me that when questions are unclear/malformed/with no code/with no actual question/etc. some people prefer to down-vote, not to ask for clarification/reformation/etc. Down-voting might not affect *experienced* users who have lots of points, but it affects *newbies*.

What is down-voting used for? Just to say 'This question is incorrect/unclear/I do not like it' ?

Comment: Downvoting an commenting to request improvement of the post are not mutually exclusive options.  In fact, if you're doing one you should at least strongly consider doing the other.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275734/voting-the-question-vs-voting-the-answer/275735#275735

Comment: you said - `some people prefer to down-vote, not to ask for clarification/reformation/etc. Down-voting might not affect experienced users who have lots of points, but it affects newbies.`  - I think it's an interesting thought, that the high-rep users can afford to get "hurt" by downvotes, while newbies are *much* more susceptible to the "harms" of downvotes. Some food for thought

Comment: @Coffee First-time posters don't have anything to lose from downvotes, the reputation does not go below 1. Consider also that an upvote grants 2.5 rep that a downvote removes, and that reputation is restored if the post is deleted. In practice, one has to work *hard* to lose even 20 points due to downvotes -- and if it comes to that, one should be worried more about getting rate-limited than about losing rep.

Comment: I have enough "reputation points" to UpVote, but not nearly the required 125 points to DownVote! If I continuously UpVote, what's the point?

Comment: @eoredson, nobody requires you to continuously upvote...

Comment: Coffee and user3717023 bring up a good point. I'm fairly new. I have a growing reputation and I don't mind losing a couple of points if a question is downvoted, but there is another consequence. Every time I post a question I am warned that if I get another downvote I will be blocked for six months. That seems a bit excessive. I have three questions with down votes and only one or two with up votes. Many that have no votes either way. So now I am at the mercy of the next person to down vote and I have no direct way of improving the questions--no feedback as to what is wrong.

Comment: @BSD, you can ask for feedback directly in the comments to your question. I often see people ask something like "Why was this downvoted?" - and some people actually answer and try to help to improve the post.

Comment: @ForceBru And I can go back once I already have the answer and edit/improve my question to be more accurate. The problem is not that I was downvoted, but that there is no balancing force. Upvotes are not required nor taken for granted. A question starts at a value of zero, so it is possible that small number of down votes on a minority of questions can affect my account which has many questions without a downvote.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is to provide a signal to anyone reading the post, thinking of reading the post, and also to the author of the post, that the post is not helpful.

For someone reading the post, it indicates that they shouldn't trust the content to be useful.  For someone thinking of reading the post they should consider whether the post is worth skipping, for the author they should attempt to improve the post.

There are also secondary effects, such as allowing posts to be deleted (automatically or manually) when they are clearly of negative value, preventing duplicate closures of posts without a "useful" answer, the ability to rate limit or even ban users with a history of providing unhelpful content, etc.  That said, all of these are systems based on the premise that downvotes are cast to reflect the fact that the voter doesn't think that the post is useful.  That signal can be used all over the place, but at its core voting is there to send a signal about the usefulness of the post.

Answer (score 14):

As a signal, to other readers [and to the system itself](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/):

> Beyond this, we’re also starting to **actively block questions from IPs and accounts that have historically produced a lot of low-quality questions.**
>
> The details of this algorithm have to be kept vague, because we don’t want people to game it or exploit it. Remember all those question votes you thought were so meaningless? You might want to reconsider that stance. The rationales for voting on questions haven’t changed, though:
>
> - if you see a great, thoughtfully asked, well researched question, vote it up — please! Great questions are an art!
> - if you see an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question that you feel was asked in bad faith … vote it down.
> - anything in between that’s salvageable, edit it — or suggest an edit if you lack the 2,000 reputation to edit outright.

We want readers to see good questions, and not see bad ones. Anyone telling you there's no such thing as a stupid question hasn't spent much time on the Internet - and those things'll really bring you down after a while. The fewer people have to look at a lousy question, the happier we are as a group.

Comment: I wish that all contributors would obey these rules - there are so many downvotes of questions that rather fit into the "anything in between" group. Especially newbies get huge downvote attacks, just because they have no experience in asking good questions. This makes me sad every time I see it...

Comment: About 20% of questions get upvoted, @nicolas. And, about 20% of questions get downvoted. However, only about 30% of questions get edited... And that overlaps heavily with the voted groups. An awful lot of people, especially those new to the site, are reluctant to edit - to them it feels rude, or forward. They'll vote or comment, but not edit. So an awful lot of questions don't get the help they need.

Comment: All of this may be true. But because there is a huge number of people that tend to behave not ideally, it is not fair to presume this to _all_ people! Every user is an individual. It is a person. And he or she may not be familiar with composing good questions. One may assume that people don't edit their questions because they are lazy. But it is possible as well that they don't know what to edit ... with what to extend their question ... how to be more precise ... what is unclear to the audience. These skills don't appear over night, just by reading the FAQ/rules! Its a learning curve instead.

Comment: Absolutely correct, @Nicolas. However, it is almost a constant that the number of people on the left edge of that curve vastly outnumber those on the rest; and that applies to both askers and potential editors.

Comment: I instantly believe you that this is true. IMHO downvotes push people to the left edge though, because downvotes have a direct implication on mood and motivation. Especially new users feel rejected by the community then. A far more better approach is to point them (directly!) to the appropriate FAQ entry. This not only trains their skills of writing a question, but it also builds their understanding for "the other side"...