# How to handle challenge about the necessity of a question

Tags: discussion

A lot of my questions seem to be met with a "what's your goal?" or "why would you want to do THAT?", challenging the validity of the request without getting into the problem, and are down-voted without explanation (this doesn't happen in all communities - RoR is more open than the go community, for example). I know that this causes me to think twice before posting a question, and I heard the same from others. How do you handle this? Do these remarks require answering?
Shouldn't there be a way for the community to regulate this?

Comment: If your question is unclear, people might want to ask *why* you want to do this in order to tell you *how* it should be done properly.

Comment: "I know that this causes me to think twice before posting a question, and I heard the same from others." - that seems to be a good thing, no? Furthermore, look up what an XY problem is. If people are constantly telling you that your requirements make no sense from their perspective, that usually either means that you're attempting something nonsensical, or that your question is unclear and does not state why this requirement is needed.

Comment: Yes, [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/245360) here :)

Comment: Thank you everybody for making my point. You down-voted a perfectly valid and clear question.
If the question is unclear, the person has to state the question is unclear. If the person wants to argue, well...
The entire point of stackoverflow is to ask and answer questions. In my 13 years of experience I haven't heard stupid questions but I guess you don't feel the same way.

Comment: I don't think that it's unreasonable to ask for more clarity of requirements, especially if they are nonsensical.  Assisting suicide is actually illegal here in the UK.  'What you are asking for is not reasonable. Tell us why you think you need it and we will tell you why you don't' IS an answer.

Comment: Again, I have 13 years of experience. I actually teach programming! No, I'm not a native English speaker, but my questions are never non sensical, and if someone asks for clarification, they will get it, but they usually down vote without explanation.

Comment: see also: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/839601)

Comment: @Ronna thank you for proving my point - you seem to seek the problem with other people, even though being told nicely that there might be a problem with yourself. This question isn't downvoted because it's _unclear_ but because it's _not useful_; people come to meta multiple times a day complayining about "unfair" downvotes, and the situation you describe makes it seem like you are simply ignoring valid advice and information (your questions requiring clarification). You also simply assert _who_ downvotes the question - unless the commenters tell you they did, you have no way of knowing this.

Comment: Also, I suspect that many of these 'unreasonable requests' arise from assignment questions where the prof is attempting to explain some point by setting a task that the student should eventually realize is not possible.  The prof knows it's stupid, the SO contributor knows it's stupid, the student just gets annoyed that nobody seems to want to help except by suggesting other approaches.

Comment: Okay, everybody's insisting that the problem is with me, so let's go over my questions so far (they are highly technical):

1. How to shuffle values in a mysql column.
2. How to pass an argument list to a function in go (exists in every other language, btw).
3. Profiling in go (google finally answered that it's in development)
4. Godep doesn't work as documented (godeps developer finally answered correctly, after someone else insisted it's in the readme and deleted his answer).
5. Dynamically add a function with a receiver in go (reflections).

Knock yourselves out fellas.

Comment: @l4mpi FWIW [even comments don't help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285253/839601): "you are free... to state that you downvoted... only that nobody else but you and Stack Exchange developers can tell whether this is true or not"

Comment: @Ronna the comments on the MySql question are IMO justified. You say you need this to anonymize test data - which means you probably don't have to do it very often and shouldn't care about performance (if you do need to regularily do that to _huge_ DBs for testing purposes, you have a process problem). You could trivially solve that with a python program that shuffles blocks of a few hundred rows and inserts them into a new DB. The go argument list one seems to fit _not useful_ as you're basically asking "is there better syntax" and the answer is "no". I didn't look at the other questions.

Comment: And btw, your MySql question is not currently downvoted; it's sitting at +1/-0. If it was downvoted at any point in time, the user(s) must have removed their DV after an edit of yours - which is how it's supposed to work with unclear questions that do receive clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Users ask questions like that because, apparently, the questions you got those comments on were unclear.

They're not questioning the validity of your question.
They're just asking from more information to help them help you.

Often enough, *why* someone needs a specific functionality explains a lot of what they're trying to do.

Comment: No, they really didn't. I could show you a bunch, but they delete their answers/ comments.

Comment: @Ronna: Without proper examples, we can't really give a accurate answer, then. If all their comments aren't contributing to the question, you could flag them as "not constructive".

Comment: @Ronna - here's one;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388341/how-to-specify-the-pthread-that-should-be-the-first-to-get-into-a-critical-regio

Comment: One big problem is that some OP's don't want to provide any further info - we might then realize that it's a copy/paste homework dump that they have made no effort to solve.

Answer (score -4):

What I always try to make my question more clever is to put a lot of code on it.
I want to show the people what I am doing and I also explain the code I am writing.
This should make people who doesn't know your application understand better the problem area and what you want to achieve.

Why you do something is a personal case. I also don't like when people ask it. As developper you do things like you want it or because you have to do it (from your boss, client).

But the main target is to describe, let people get in your story. The problem becomes more clear when you know the big context of it.

Comment: More code isn't necessarily better. I agree that letting other users know ad much detail as possible is a good idea though.

Comment: Letting people into your story seems to make things worse, they decide the question is unclear, and attack your motivation instead of answer the problem. See my first question ever here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518594/how-to-shuffle-a-column-in-mysql

Comment: With more code I mean ofcourse code which is necessairy to understand the problem concept. People who attack your motivation aren't good helpers, I ignore those guys. Remember, bad questions doesn't exist, bad answers do.

Comment: What?  Bad questions surely do exist!  Of course people will attack your motivation if the questions is unreasonable.  Suggesting alternative, and sane, approaches to some development issue is fine.  Mindlessly attempting to provide solutions to silly requirements is not - who wants that on a Q&A site, (except maybe assignment-dumpers who have been specifically forbidden to use such approaches)?

Comment: @MartinJames ["Anyone telling you there's no such thing as a stupid question hasn't spent much time on the Internet..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284585/839601) :)

Comment: You should give new people here more credits. It's not that easy to immediately produce perfect questions...

Comment: @JonasAudenaert  Too many 'new' people are clueless, not necessarily about software, but how to ask for assistance in general.  How many of them would call their garage and ask for help with 'My car won't go'?  It is easy to immediately produce good questions,  questions with as much relevant info as reasonably possible. It is, however, also very easy to produce very bad questions, and new people seem to be very good at that.

Comment: Some people can do it from the beginning, some don't. Don't forget you we're ever new as well.