# I'm not new to programming. I'm not bad at googling. How do I avoid being considered stupid for asking "stupid" questions?

Tags: discussion

**"Basically, the things I tried first, and the things I read first, were what everyone thought I was too stupid to find or read."**

The case:

I want to know what the Swift programming language is all about, why I should learn a new one, what it might replace, what's broken in it, and what it fixes. All the basics of a new tool.

The problem:

People seem to source only the Apple documentation and Wikipedia for information. These do not give a balanced pros vs cons list. Nor does searching for one help, because so many people moved from Objective-C that almost all links will lead to it being better than Objective-C, but it works with it too. No comparison to any other languages, and certainly no rants about what's broken in it.

The BIG problem:

I tried asking the community. A bunch of people told me I'm an idiot if I don't think Apple is the best source of information on users experiences with it. I suck at googling (followed by "let me google that for you" links which I had already searched and which had absolutely no good reviews or answers). Basically, the things I tried first, and the things I read first, were what everyone thought I was too stupid to find or read.

The question:

How do you posit a question like this? One where it seems like a simple Google search would yield a result, but it absolutely does not. Nor a complex one. Nor many pages of many different complex ones ("The Swift language pros and cons -taylor -objective", Swift language why use -taylor -objective").

How do I find an answer to this "stupid simple" question? Also ARGGRGR the guy who told me I'm an idiot for not thinking Apple documentation were a trustworthy source on whether or not I should learn their language. I am just saying. It irked me.

Comment: The biggest road block here would be pro/con questions tend to be pretty broad and/or too opinionated. That question is usually better suited for somewhere other than SO, such as a mailinglist or blogger. It is possible to ask an on topic pro/con question, but you've gotta be **very** specific in what you are asking for so that it doesn't become an endless list.

Comment: If you are being harassed regarding posts you make, you can consider reporting this through the proper channels (whether it be happening on SO or elsewhere.) That said, the question you propose seems like it can easily be regarded as too broad or open to opinion, which is probably why you're getting such feedback.

Comment: That question is off topic, so it's not a big surprise you'd get pushback.  I doubt you were told that you're an idiot.

Comment: You're probably right.  But it's definitely not bad form for a programmer to look into something like this.

Comment: *"not bad form for a programmer to look into something like this"* Not at all, it's just not something that fits into a Q/A format, just like discussing your favorite language, or favorite food.

Comment: It's bad form to jump into a community and ask questions of a type they specifically have marked as off topic.

Comment: I suppose so.  It's really too bad.  Swift might actually be a decent language for me to learn, but my only option at the moment is to dive in and figure out if I like it later.

Comment: @Will I've been in this community for a while.  I know what types of questions are on here.  Ruby vs. Python is a Q&A that got marked as bad which I really really like.  It has very relevant information to what I was searching for when I found it.

Comment: A forum or irc/chat would be a decent place to discuss this type of topic too, but i'm not familiar enough with the languages you're looking at to suggest one where you'd get unbiased opinions.

Comment: [Is there a problem with Stack Overflow when extremely useful massively upvoted questions get closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92980) [Why are useful questions on Stack Overflow being closed as non-constructive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110350)

Comment: The people who responded so negatively were not in the interest of shared information either.  It was much more an outlet for their own "coder insecurities" if you ask me.  Being mean is usually not good.

Comment: Stack Overflow has deliberately chosen to exclude some potentially useful questions because the vast majority of questions of that form are not useful.  That's okay -- there are plenty of other sites on the Web; Stack Overflow doesn't have to do everything.

Comment: Yeah.  That makes sense.  But I searched for those sites first, y'know?  That's exactly what I go out looking for.  This time, there weren't any.

Comment: Yeah... consider the question 'I need a motor vehicle.  Which one should I consider?'.

Comment: Seph, if you looked into those other sites... maybe this is where you should bring your question? Stack doesn't have to be the be all end all of everything programming.

Comment: There weren't any.  I went to reddit/swift, and that's the best I could find.  And asking for the cons on there is not going to be unbiased either.

"This isn't I need a motor vehicle."  This was "The truck was just invented, what would I need it for, what's a reason not to get it, what is a reason to.  Why can't I find anything but ads?"

Comment: Really, the problem is that SO was my last choice.  The last place I felt I could turn to, after everything else failed.  And it was right of me to not want to, but I value information enough to risk "rep"

Comment: Wow, so you specifically asked an off topic question.  That's nice.

Comment: @Seph, then, if you got to reddit/swift, why not ask your question there? They are not against opinionated questions.... If you KNOW your question will be off topic here.... I think posting it is very counter productive

Comment: I think one of the important steps in the personal development of a programmer is to lose your fear of being thought stupid; and indeed to lose your fear that when you criticise others, you are accusing them of being stupid. Direct your criticism at the work, not the worker, and accept criticism of your work in the same way. We all have vast areas of ignorance, and we all have days on which we fail to see the obvious solution to a problem, and yet none of us is stupid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the record, I don't see anyone being particularly rude to you in the comments on [your (self-deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34273855/19679). As others have stated, the question was extremely broad and was unclear in even what you were looking for. Most of the comments there were trying to clarify what you meant by "trustworthy" documentation, or even what you were trying to learn about regarding the language.

If you do find comments to be rude or condescending, flag them and we'll take a look at them. Don't try to respond in kind, because that rarely leads to things getting better. I think some people may have responded poorly to the targeted comments you were leaving, when they just wanted clarification about what you were asking.

Describing an entire language and when you might or might not use it (particularly for a language that's only been available for a year and a half) is far outside the scope of a question on Stack Overflow. Thankfully, tons of people have been analyzing and pontificating on the language over the last year.

As suggested, start with Apple's documentation, which at least introduces their arguments for the language and what they feel it is intended to solve. You may not trust this take, but it gives you a starting point. I highly recommend the [Introduction to Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-402/) video from WWDC 2014, which introduces many of the arguments for the language.

From there, try searches for ["swift programming language opinions"](https://www.google.com/#q=swift+programming+language+opinions) or ["swift programming language downsides"](https://www.google.com/#q=swift+programming+language+downsides) to find more critical takes, mixed in with the praise. A lot of people have had a lot to say about the language, so it's hard to find someone without an opinion on it. Try refining your search based on what you want to do with the language. There are large differences between what might be positive or negative in a server-side, mobile, scripting, etc. environment. A huge number of discussions have taken place on Reddit [in a variety of language-specific subreddits](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/27nez1/apple_invents_m%E2%80%A6). You'll find a lot of critiques in there.

Of the more nuanced critiques out there, I recommend [this podcast episode by Wolf Rentzsch and Andrew Pontious](http://edgecasesshow.com/099-swift-is-a-really-good-thing-and-a-step-back.html) where they present a more skeptical take on the language, or some of Brent Simmons' thoughts on it [here](http://inessential.com/swiftdiary). These are just some that I've come across myself in the natural process of searching for counterpoints. Personally, I tend to have a [more](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/12/02/why-were-rewriting-our-robotics-software-swift) [positive](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2015/11/03/what-we-learned-rewriting-our-robotic-control-software-swift) outlook on the language, so you may not be interested in what I have to say.

Comment: I'm absolutely interested in what you and anyone else has to say.  Thank you very much for your response, it appears to be filled with valuable information.

I said this in comments elsewhere, but whatever my web searching was doing last night, it is not doing it today.  The big difference being that I did my first few searches on DuckDuckGo and that I was searching "apple swift" rather than "swift language."  It made a MASSIVE difference in yielded search results for me.   Thank you though.

Answer (score 10):

Let's start with the main issue:  Stack Exchange (as a whole) is meant for concrete and specific answers to a question, and is not suited for or capable of supporting list-only or compare/contrast style questions.  With that in mind, your question would not be on topic on Stack Overflow or anywhere around here.

<sup>I mean, I *would* suggest chat, but it's such a different beast unto itself that I can't guarantee that you'd get what you're looking for from it.</sup>

Now to the underlying question:

> I want to know what swift programming language is all about, why I should learn a new one, what it might replace, what's broken in it, what it fixes.

There is a lot of news and a lot of content already on the 'Net concerning Swift, and what it's meant to do, but what you're trying to understand is fairly broad in and of itself.  Kind of like you're trying to drink straight from the firehose when all you need is a few glasses here and there.

Break this up into easier to digest pieces, as this will make your search effort easier.

- What is the actual language/syntax?  (You may also want to look into some books along this line.)
- Why was it created? (There is at least one YouTube video outlining why Swift came to be.)
- What are its use cases?
- What platforms could I write code for with Swift?

The rest can come later as you use it (especially the "broken" part; no sense in working around a pain point if you're not actually pained by it).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a broad question.  I get that they don't belong here, I'll concede.  But it's not like trying to drink from a fire hose.  It's more like walking into a tool store and seeing a new tool.  You should want to know about it's functionality and the range on it's worst to best case scenario.  The details will come later.

Comment: The difference here? Stack doesn't offer that tool. So I don't think it HAS to offer the manual as well

Comment: I'd say that it's the difference between the tangible and intangible.  Unlike a physical tool, which you'd have to purchase and take home with you before you truly discovered its capabilities, a language like Swift would at least allow you to play around with it while asking questions.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. At its core it is opinion based and even if you reworded it, it would still be too broad.

The only place on the SE network where you might get away with soliciting opinions would be [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check the FAQ for each room before posting.

Comment: HOLY CRAP!!!!!!!!!!!  There's a place I can ask questions like this!?!

DUDE.  Thank you.  Thank you so much.  I didn't know this feature existed, and I have SOOOOOOOOOO sooo many questions about:  Have you tried this?  How'd it work out for you?

There are so many different versions of everything, I can't try them all.

Comment: @SephReed Tread carefully in chat, some of the old guard can get a little touchy if you flood their room.

Comment: Errmmm...... be VERY careful.....

Comment: @MartinJames perhaps "a little touchy" wasn't the best phrasing...

Comment: Okay.  Dually noted.

I still can't believe it.  I've searched for over a day and I can't find one negative opinion about Swift.  Anywhere.  It makes me sick.  Like my search engine is that broken, and the internet is that... I don't know the word.  Incomplete.

Comment: @SephReed That unfortunately seems to be a common occurrence with new programming languages. Early on, you get a lot of early adopters who praise it like the best thing since sliced bread, then the next thing comes out and they all of a sudden start seeing it's flaws, and move to the new "best thing." it's sickening. I hate the "best practices"/"best language"/"best library" game that has begun.

Comment: But I can't even find "the flaws."  Not one.  Not one single thing wrong with it anywhere on the internet.  I know if anyone was in my position they would see that something is very very broken here.  Like, actually makes me nauseous.

Comment: @SephReed: ["swift language sucks"](https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+language+sucks)? Also, BNR weren't big fans last I checked. Their blog might have some stuff.

Comment: FIRST THING I SEARCHED.

A lot of people don't like Taylor Swift, btw

Comment: The [entire first page of hits for that search](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jng3f.png) is about the language, @SephReed.

Comment: "swift language sucks -taylor" gives ONE decent result.  It's the first piece of information I've found.

Comment: holy crap.  it is.

Comment: I literally searched this last night and got nothing

Comment: what just happened?

Comment: and thank you.  I don't know why things are so different today vs. last night.  Maybe I searched "why swift language sucks" or something.  But it was literally my first search.  It's always the first thing I search on anything.  And then "why I love X"

Comment: Seriously though.  thank you.  I've had a headache for like 4 hours over this.  I'm probably going to delete all this now though.  I don't think anyone will believe me when I say that the solution to my problem was the first thing I did, and it just didn't work.

Answer (score -11):

In my opinion there is no *stupid* question. There may be *misguided* questions but those a strong question should be put together before referring to any resource.

**When to use Google:**

- When you are search documentation for a piece of code that has a key word
- Broad ideas

**When to use Overflow:**

- When you have specific code samples you have questions
- When you have more technical questions you need specific answers

When posting questions just do your best to be specific and only put in information and the people on here are pretty nice and helpful. Work your way up on the site and you'll learn as you go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not new to SO.  It's a new account, that's about it.

Google yielded no results.

Comment: "Anyone telling you there's no such thing as a stupid question hasn't spent much time on the Internet..." ([Purpose of down-voting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284585/839601))

Comment: And I'm sorry, but the nice helpful people thing is only going to get you hurt.  This site is policed heavily.  It's a vent for aggression for many.  Being nice is a great idea, but it may not come back around.